# React constructor ES6 vs ES7

Tags: reactjs

I read on the React tutorials page that ES6 will use constructor functions to initialize state like this.

```
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Counter.propTypes = { initialCount: React.PropTypes.number };
Counter.defaultProps = { initialCount: 0 };
```

Then it continues, using ES7 syntax to achieve the same thing.

```
// Future Version
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = { initialCount: React.PropTypes.number };
  static defaultProps = { initialCount: 0 };
  state = { count: this.props.initialCount };
  tick() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why is ES7 better then ES6 version or ES5 version.

Thanks

Comment: This ES7 syntax is new to me. Can you please post that webpage where you found it? I would be surprised if Facebook, after taking so much time to give React an ES6 overhaul, would get rid of the constructor which gives developers the feel of Java or some other object-oriented language.

Comment: Yes it is here.https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html

Comment: in the second (ES7) example, the "tick" method could be written `tick = () => {...};` or even shorter... `tick = () => this.setState(...);` right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ES7 is better because it enables the following scenarios:

- Where declarative interpretation of expectations are useful. Some examples include editors so that they can make use of this info for typeaheads/inference, TypeScript/Flow can make use of this to allow their users to express intentions about the shapes of their classes
- Allowing general users to use this for just human-readable documentation about properties separate from potentially complex initialization logic
- Possibly allow VMs to pre-emptively optimize objects created from a class with some of these hints on them.

*Note:* When you define your state by using ES7, you are using `Property initializers` feature

References: [Class field declarations for JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)